# Information propagating at less than the speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, causality, information, thought-experiment

Which speed does information propagate at in a medium?
For example, if we live in a pool which is one light-year cube and somebody dewaters of the pool from an observer which is at 1 light-year distance. Will the observer experience the effect of the event after 1 light-year or longer? Put the question another way, will the observer experience the effect of the event first and after that, he will realize that someone dewaters of the pool.

So now I extend my question. If the graviton propagates with the speed of light in any medium and I know that the photon propagates with less than c (lets it propagates with v) in some specific medium. Then I build two detectors to find where electromagnetic and gravitational wave emitting objects are. It is like earthquake detectors. right?

Comment: BTW, a 1 light-year cube of water is impossible. It'd have about 100 million times the mass of the Milky Way. But even if you could obtain that much water it'd turn into a black hole long before it got that big. In fact, a sphere of water with mass around 1.36 solar masses (which would have a radius of 1338 light-seconds if we ignore compression, and the fact that nuclear fusion will be taking place) is smaller than its Schwarzschild radius.

Comment: yes yes you are right but because of this impossibility, folk called it Gedanke experiment.

Comment: There is no principle dictating that information propagates at $c$, or at any other speed. There is only a principle that it *can't* propagate *faster* than $c$.

Answer (score 4):

Actually he will see that something is happening in the other part of the pool (with light) before he will feel anything, because "dewatering" will send a sound wave in the medium, which is much slower than the speed of light in the medium.

Anyhow, one can send information faster than light in a medium, if the light is slow enough, high energy particles (like neutrons, electrons, neutrino, etc...) can travel faster and deliver information faster than light. If a charged particle does that, Cherenkov radiation is emitted by those particle.

So to sum up: information will never travel faster than $c$ because that breaks some rules from special relativity. But if the speed of light is lower than $c$, particles with a velocity bigger than light can transfer information faster. However, information concerning pressure, density and other flow parameters travel at the speed of sound via the interactions between molecules in the medium and that is very slow, meaning you will see someone dewater and only then feel anything due to the water flowing.

Answer (score 1):

We say that information propagates at the speed of light because if we have to transmit a message through a medium, the most effective way to do it would be through light. We do it among ourselves through sound but light is the fastest.

Continuing from your example, if the observer had an all-powerful telescope which could see from light years away; he would see it a year later because that time was taken by light to reach there. Hence if aliens were ever to zoom in on earth with their own telescope, they would very likely see dinosaurs.

Answer (score 1):

Gravity also moves at the speed of light in a vacuum, nothing moves faster than light, so any information sent by any method would take at least 1 year to travel 1 light year. The Sun is about 8 light minutes from Earth, so if the Sun suddenly disappeared, we would still see it, and continue in orbit around where it was for about 8 minutes. In a large pool of water, anything done at the other end would be seen at the speed of light, which is a little slower in a medium than it is in a vacuum, and then could be felt at the water's speed of sound.